# Can't connect to home server

Tags: router, apache-http-server, webserver, xampp

Trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong.  I installed XAMPP - and everything looks fine.  If I go to localhost everything comes right up.  But when I go to my IP address, I just  get a message that the browser could not connect to it.  I go into my router and set up port forwarding for port 80 etc, and I even tried putting the server as a DMZ - still nothing.  I turned the firewall off to see if that was interfering in some way, then uninstalled it completely for good measure, made no difference.  I'm out of ideas..  oh, and yes I have a static IP address.

Comment: Is this for while you are on your home network, outside of it or both?

Comment: I can't access it from inside or outside the network by IP

Comment: Can you access it via the public ip from an address NOT on your network (ie, the library, local Starbucks, a friend's house, etc)? If the answer is yes, then you need to enable something called NAT reflection (which not all routers name the same thing, nor do all routers allow to toggle it).

Comment: when you say "when I go to my IP address", is this your servers ip, your gateway ip address or your public ip address? And what happens to all?

Comment: Can you tell us what operating system you're on?